# How to get a similar effect using mouseenter() with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i created dropdown menu, and when i click on the main item, it opens a dropdown menu

Here is the Fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/tjf22z6p/177/

I need this same effect with the `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` or any other effective way to do that. Thanks

Comment: Just change the events accordingly?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tjf22z6p/179/

Comment: it is correct. but if you try to hover on the children li, the dropdown menu goes up.

Comment: [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to account for mouseenter, mouseleave. But can leave the rest of the code the same:

```
$('.language').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
    $('.languageDropdown').slideToggle(400);
});
```

or you can also achieve the same without using jQuery/javascript and using CSS with just a little change to the markup: http://jsfiddle.net/k4n6rnmr/

CSS:

```
.languageDropdown{
  display:none;
}
.language:hover .languageDropdown{
  display: block;
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
}
```

Mark-up:

```
 <div class="language">
      <a href="#">
         ENG 
      </a>
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <ul class="languageDropdown">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          ENGLISH
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          SPANISH
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          ARABIC
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          TELUGU
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a wrapping element to stay on hover while you enter the list with your curser. Then Put a hover and a leave event listener on it.

Check this example:

```js
// Language DropDown on the top of the menu

$('.languageDropdown').hide();


$(".language").mouseover(function(){
 $(".languageDropdown").slideDown(400);
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $(".languageDropdown").slideUp(400);
});
```

```css
.languageDropdown{
  display:none;
}
ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="language">
          <a href="#">
             ENG 
          </a>
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <ul class="languageDropdown">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              ENGLISH
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              SPANISH
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              ARABIC
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              TELUGU
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```